# Conceptual question about second isomorphism theorem for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following doubt.

If $G$ is a group, $N\trianglelefteq G$and $H\leq G$, we know from the second isomorphism theorem that:

$N\cap H\trianglelefteq H$   and   $\displaystyle \frac{H}{N\cap H}\cong \frac{HN}{N}$.

My question is... How does the group $(HN/N)$ looks like? I mean, an element in that group has the form $(hn)N$, isn't it equal to $(hN)(nN)=(hN)(N)=hN$? So, if this is the case, it seems that this group is actually isomorphic to $H/N$, but this group can have no sense (since $N$ may not be included in $H$).

Another thing that still bothers me is that the proof of the second isomorphism theorem works with $NH/N$ in place of $HN/N$, but in this case I can't find the annoying concept problem. Is really $HN$ equal to $NH$?

I want to find the flaw in this argument, please help me guys. Greetings.

Comment: for subgroups $H,K\leq G$, $HK=KH$ if at least one of them is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, observe that an element of $HN$ could be expressed in several different forms:

Suppose that $hn=h'n' \in HN$. Your argument will give $$hN=h'N,$$
which means that $HN/N$ is not quite the same as $H/N$ since some distinct elements of $H/N$ coincide in $HN/N$.

For your second question, the condition which makes $HN$ into a group is the equality $$HN=NH,$$ so that the two are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that $H/N$ does not make sense because $H$ does not necessarily contain $N$. However, there is a way to make sense of $H/N$:

Consider the quotient homomorphism $q:G \to G/N$. Then $q(H)$ is a subgroup of $G/N$ and so $q^{-1}(q(H))$ is subgroup of $G$ that contains $N$. This subgroup is exactly $HN$ and $q(HN)=q(H)$. So, $HN/N = q(HN)$ is a close as you get to $q(H)"="H/N$.